# How many total states do you need to prove that union of two regular languages also gives you a regular language?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

I am reading a book called *Introduction of the Theory of Computation*. In the book, the author tries to proof $A_1 \cup A_2$ is regular if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are regular.

He is using *Proof by Construction*. I understood that we have to construct $M$ from $M_1$ which recognizes $A_1$ and $M_2$ which recognizes $A_2$ in order to proof that union of two regular languages also gives you regular language.

But I am not understanding this statement, "If $M_1$ has $k_1$ states and $M_2$ has $k_2$ states, the number of pairs of states, one from $M_1$ and the other $M_2$, is the product $k_1 \times k_2$."

Shouldn't be the number of states for $M$ be the addition of $M_1$ and $M_2$ and initial state for $M$?

For Example, if $M_1$ has 3 states and $M_2$ has 3 states, then $M$ should have $M_1$'s states  and $M_2$'s states and one additional state for the initial state for $M$. In total 7 states. But the book is saying, we should have $3 \times 3 = 9$ states.

I know I am stupid and wrong. But can you explain it as you are explaining to a 5-year old kid?

Comment: Consider a symbol $a$ from the input alphabet, and suppose that $M_1$, if it gets $a$ as its first input symbol, goes to state $s$. Similarly, suppose that $M_2$,  if it gets $a$ as its first input symbol, goes to state $t$. Now what will your $7$-state $M$ do if it gets $a$ as its first input symbol? Should it go to $s$? Or to $t$? Or some other one of its $7$ states?

Comment: @AndreasBlass  It's a good question to ask. I know in NFA, symbol "a" would go to both s and t states. They can run parallel (simultaneously) . But I'm having hard time picturing it in DFA.

Answer (score 3):

The book is, presumably, building a deterministic finite automaton from two deterministic finite automata. You, however, are building a non-deterministic automaton: from your new initial state, you have $\varepsilon$-transitions to the initial states of $M_1$ and $M_2$.